# Merging a list of dicts into one dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts which are guaranteed to have the same keys. Each element of a dict is a list. What's the most elegant way to merge these dicts into one dict extending the lists of the same keys?

I have:

```py
[
    {
        'x': ['a', 'b'],
        'y': ['c', 'd']
    },
    {
        'x': ['e', 'f'],
        'y': ['g', 'h']
    },
]
```

I want:

```py
{
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
    'y': ['c', 'd', 'g', 'h']
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the question added is what OP needs

Comment: I've edited the duplicate list to point to appropriate questions.